# A is inversible if and only if $rank(A)=n$ complex matrice?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$

I know that :

> A is invertible if and only if $rank(A)=n$

Does the conclusion remains valid for $A$ a complex matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general property of matrices over any field, so it works for the complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any reference please ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)

Comment: I know that but I cannot see the proof..

Comment: http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/thm_full_rank_pd.html

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a matrix is invertible iff the nullspace of that matrix is trivial. The Rank-Nullity theorem tells us that $$Rank(A) + Nullity(A) = n.$$ Thus if $Rank(A) = n$ then we have $Nullity(A) = 0$. This means the dimension of the nullspace is 0, and we have $A$ is invertible.